# Maximizing user preferences window

Tags: javascript, xml, jira, opensocial, jira-plugin

I am working on an opensocial gadget inside of a JIRA plugin. I need to have the 'userpreferences' window resize to the full size of the gadget rather than just take up the top 1/3 as is default. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?